# Enable the "Make "New Folder" command available?" option with Sharepoint using @pnp/sp

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointdocumentlibrary, pnp-js, sharepointframework

I need to create folder under Site Pages library under SharePoint Online site.

I have tried to create the folder programmatically using **@pnp/sp** library. But it thrown me Access Denied error.

New Folder option is missing while click on New. Please check below screenshot,
[image]

I have check the solutions for the same and I got the solution if New folder option will enable then I can create new page.

So, I need to enable New Folder option programmatically using **@pnp/sp** library as per the below screenshot,
[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow folder creation. Go to library settings -> advance settings-> Set to yes "Make "New Folder" command available?"

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I need to do that programmatically using @pnp/sp. Do you have any idea to achieve the same using @pnp/sp?

Comment: It is one time config per site, so you can do it manualy maybe. I am not sure if you can do it via pnp/sp. For sure you can achive it via pnp powershell by running
"Set-PnPList -Identity "Documents" -EnableFolderCreation 1 "

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I need to do that programmatically using @pnp/sp

Comment: I don`t think it is possible. Check microsoft graph

Comment: I have achieve the same using @sp/pnp. Here is the link for the same.
https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/folders/#add
Thank you again.